# While executing the package getting below error

Tags: ssis

[Excel Source [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
[Excel Source [2]] Error: Failed to retrieve long data for column "Management Acceptance \ Comments".
[Excel Source [2]] Error: There was an error with Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output] on Excel Source. The column status returned was: "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".
[Excel Source [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]" failed because error code 0xC0209071 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Excel Source" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.